# Trying to create a image slider without jQuery

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to get this image slider to work without jQuery; using font awesome icons as my next and previous buttons. When I change the value of the `imgCounter` variable the image changes however I cant get it to work properly.

```js
var $ = function(id) {
  return document.getElementById(id);
};

var imgCounter = 0;

var next = function() {

  if (imgCounter < 6) {
    imgCounter++;
  } else {
    imgCounter = 0;
  }
}

window.onload = function() {
  // where image will display
  var imageNode = $('display');
  var slideNode = $('slides');
  // gathers all the images in an array
  var slides = document.getElementsByClassName('img');
  //to target a specific index
  imgCounter = imgCounter % slides.length;

  var image = slides[imgCounter];
  //to switch the current photo with the next one in the array
  imageNode.src = image.src;
  $('right').onclick = next;
};
```

```html
<section id="slider">
  <img id="display" src="" alt="display" />

  <i id="left" class="fa fa-arrow-left fa-4x" aria-hidden="true"></i>
  <i id="right" class="fa fa-arrow-right fa-4x" aria-hidden="true"></i>
  <div id="slides">
    <img class="img" src="images/20anniversary-large.png" alt="anniversary" />
    <img class="img" src="images/53rd.jpg" alt="53rd" />
    <img class="img" src="images/Award.png" alt="Award">
    <img class="img" src="images/rotator-03-lg.jpg" alt="rotator-03-lg" />
    <img class="img" src="images/rotator01lg.jpg" alt="rotator01lg" />
    <img class="img" src="images/rotator-02-lg.jpg" alt="rotator-02-lg" />
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Have a look at this: https://jsfiddle.net/t2emherc/

Comment: can you explain what isn't working for you? Just saying it isn't working properly doesn't clarify what issues you are actually having.

Comment: sorry, when i clicked on the next button it didnt change the images.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't really follow your code but I created a pure JavaScript, CSS, HTML solution. See this JSBin so you can see it in action: https://jsbin.com/kixofal/5/edit?html,css,js,output

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="slider" data-showing="2">
    <div class="slide image-1"></div>
    <div class="slide image-2"></div>
    <div class="slide image-3"></div>
  </div>
  <button class="button previous">left</button>
  <button class="button next">right</button>
</body>
</html>
```

JAVASCRIPT:

```
function initSlider() {
  var slider = document.querySelector("#slider");
  var previousButton = document.querySelector(".previous");
  var nextButton = document.querySelector(".next");
  var slides = slider.querySelectorAll(".slide");
  var animationDuration = 700;
  
  // put slides in it's initial place
  var currentIndex = slider.dataset.showing * 1;
  [].forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll(".slide"), function(elem, i){
    i = i+1; // index starts at 0
    if(i === currentIndex) return;
    elem.style.transform = i < currentIndex ? "translateX(-100%)" : "translateX(100%)";
  });
  
  // prevent user from bursting through the slides.
  function onAnimationEnd() {
    clearTimeout(slider.isMoving);
    slider.isMoving = undefined;
  }
  
  function moveSlide(animationName){
    var direction = 0;
    if(animationName === "left") direction = -1;
    if(animationName === "right") direction = 1;

    return function() {
      // check if it is currently moving
      if(!isNaN(slider.isMoving)) return;
      // some old devices might skip a few animationEnd events
      // setTimeout is used as a last reource to prevent that to happen.
      slider.isMoving = setTimeout(onAnimationEnd, animationDuration + 50);

      var current = slider.dataset.showing * 1;
      var next = current + direction;
      if(next < 1) next = 3;
      if(next > slides.length) next = 1;

      var currentSlide = slider.querySelector(".image-" + current);
      var nextSlide = slider.querySelector(".image-" + next);

      currentSlide.style.animationName = "slide-out-" + animationName;
      nextSlide.style.animationName = "slide-in-from-" + animationName;

      slider.dataset.showing = next;
    };
  }
  
  previousButton.addEventListener("click", moveSlide("left"), false);
  nextButton.addEventListener("click", moveSlide("right"), false);
  slider.addEventListener("animationend", onAnimationEnd, false);
}

window.addEventListener("load", initSlider, false);
```

CSS:

```
#slider {
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  /* viewport units to keep the ratio */
  height: 50vw;
}

.slide {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: 50% 50%;
  
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  animation-duration: 700ms;
  animation-timing-function: ease;  
}

.image-1 {
  background-image: url("http://www.freedigitalphotos.net/images/img/homepage/87357.jpg");
}

.image-2 {
  background-image: url("http://www.gettyimages.pt/gi-resources/images/Homepage/Hero/PT/PT_hero_42_153645159.jpg");
}

.image-3 {
  background-image: url("http://www.gettyimages.ca/gi-resources/images/Homepage/Hero/UK/CMS_Creative_164657191_Kingfisher.jpg");
}

// animations

@keyframes slide-out-left {
  from { transform: translateX(0); }
  to { transform: translateX(-100%); }
}
@keyframes slide-out-right {
  from { transform: translateX(0); }
  to { transform: translateX(100%); }
}

@keyframes slide-in-from-left {
  from { transform: translateX(100%); }
  to { transform: translateX(0); }
}
@keyframes slide-in-from-right {
  from { transform: translateX(-100%); }
  to { transform: translateX(0); }
}
```

---

## Edit

I forgot to mention, this solution is missing browser prefixes, which I avoided to try and keep the solution clean.

Also, this solution doesn't use jQuery or any other external modules, and it is rather focused on allowing the GPU render the slide change (trying to optimize the animation so that every device can render it smoothly).

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sample framework to play around with:

```js
var $ = function(query) {
  return document.querySelector(query);
};

var $all = function(query) {
  return document.querySelectorAll(query);
};

var imageSlider = (function() {

  var imgCounter = 0;

  var next = function() {
    imgCounter++;
    if (imgCounter >= $all('.img').length) {
      imgCounter = 0;
    }
    changeImage();
  }

  var changeImage = function() {
    var imageNode = $('#display');
    var slides = $all('.img');
    var image = slides[imgCounter];
    imageNode.src = image.src;
  }

  return {
    changeImage: changeImage,
    next: next
  }
})();

window.onload = function() {
  imageSlider.changeImage();
  $('#right').onclick = function() {
    imageSlider.next();
  }
};
```

```css
div#slides > img {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<section id="slider">
  <i id="left" class="fa fa-arrow-left fa-4x" aria-hidden="true">Left</i>
  <img id="display" src="" alt="My ducks slider" />
  <i id="right" class="fa fa-arrow-right fa-4x" aria-hidden="true">Right</i>
  <div id="slides">
    <img class="img" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/b/bf/Bucephala-albeola-010.jpg/220px-Bucephala-albeola-010.jpg" alt="anniversary" />
    <img class="img" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/5/54/Mallard_drake_.02.jpg/220px-Mallard_drake_.02.jpg" alt="53rd" />
    <img class="img" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/5/51/Mandarin.duck.arp.jpg/220px-Mandarin.duck.arp.jpg" alt="Award">
    <img class="img" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/f/f2/Mallard_drake_and_blue_mood.jpg/220px-Mallard_drake_and_blue_mood.jpg" alt="rotator-03-lg" />
    <img class="img" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/5/52/Ducks_in_the_ponds.JPG/220px-Ducks_in_the_ponds.JPG" alt="rotator01lg" />
    <img class="img" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/a/a6/Parrulo_-Muscovy_duckling.jpg/220px-Parrulo_-Muscovy_duckling.jpg" alt="rotator-02-lg" />
  </div>
</section>
```